# Ban users from their IP

Tags: 7

I need to install a module that permit me (on my site) to ban IP. I have searched on Drupal.org and Google.com, but seems that there is not a good solution. All modules seems abandoned, so I ask here if someone use one of these modules and which one use. I don't want to start a thread about which is the best, only know which one I can use.

Comment: why you dont use drupal default ip ban in `admin/config/people/ip-blocking` ????

Answer (score 5):

The built-in IP blocking (at /admin/config/people/ip-blocking) works just fine, but if you're looking for some slightly more advanced functionality, like blocking ranges of IPs, I've used [IP Ranges](https://drupal.org/project/ip_ranges) with a great deal of success:

> IP Ranges is a module that let's you completely ban both single IP-addresses as well as
>   full ranges from your site. The ban is triggered already at the early bootstrap phase, so you
>   can get rid of unwanted visitors as early as possible without wasting server resources.
>
> You can also define whitelists that override blacklists, both single and ranged.
>   The UI is similar to core ip-ban, so you will feel like home immediately.

Comment: great success! http://www.quickmeme.com/img/40/40b96f717103244d7d9dea023de22820619058efade0a529f2938430963ed6c7.jpg
Now legitimate users within the whole RANGE of the IP banned users cannot use your service. IP banning is silly in general. Ban one IP: User can get a new dynamic one. Next user that gets old IP will be banned. Ban whole range: You can take out a section of your userbase if you keep doing that regularly.

Comment: @David Perhaps you're unfamiliar with administering large, popular websites. This module, and others like it, are a very important tool in combatting spam. When you've got millions of users, blocking a single one by mistake whilst keeping out hundreds of thousands of spam bots is a no-brainer.

Comment: I see. In that case, fair enough.

Comment: @David It's definitely not ideal, I'll give you that, but if you've got a better way I'd be genuinely delighted to hear it :)

Comment: @Clive BadBehavior is often a better long term option than this, but IP blocking is good for triage.

Comment: @MPD I haven't used that one before, looks good. I find [Spambot](https://drupal.org/project/spambot) a tremendous help too on bigger sites (though you have to weight the traffic up against the extra HTTP requests, can outweigh the benefits sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

In second the recommendation of the built-in IP blocking already metioned by Clive

If you want more features, the [Anonymous Publishing](https://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) module let you:

- let the administrator block abusers based on e-mail & IP address

What it does (beyond the basic module) is to let the admin block based upon observed abusive behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure it blocks users totally? Not only from anonymous publishing feature?

Comment: @Molot, yes.  The IP-blocking piggybacks on the built-in IP blocking. It just helps the admin spot the "most" abused IP-addresses in order to block them.